# How to compile Unsafe code in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I've imported an API function like

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
private unsafe static extern bool SetDeviceGammaRamp(Int32 hdc, void* ramp);
```

while compiling its showing an error like

```
Unsafe code may only appear if compiling with /unsafe
```

how to compile with `/unsafe` . i'm using `Microsoft Visual Studio 2008`

can any one help me with a better solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

right click on project. properties. build. check allow unsafe code

Comment: no. right click on project name to open it's menu, so you can go to properties.

Comment: oh. i thought the menu in the toolbar. Either way we can use. right?

Comment: in the solution explorer. sorry, forgot to mention.

Answer (score 3):

Just delete the *unsafe* keyword from the declaration.  Windows API functions like this are not unsafe.  You can get rid if the awkward void* (IntPtr in managed code) like this:

```
    private struct RAMP {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
        public UInt16[] Red;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
        public UInt16[] Green;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
        public UInt16[] Blue;
    }

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetDeviceGammaRamp(IntPtr hDC, ref RAMP lpRamp);
```

Also note that the first argument is a handle, an IntPtr, not an Int32.  Required to make this code work on 64-bit operating systems.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the screenshot if someone needs.

[image: UnsafeCodeImage]